# Change the position of a word in directory name

Tags: linux, command-line, directory, rename

I have several hundred directories currently in this form :

Band Name - Album Name (year)

I would like to rename everything (with a mass treatment) in
Band Name (Year) Album Name

Almost all of my directories have this naming rule (with a few exceptions ready)
Not being an expert in bash scripting, I'm here to ask for your help. Thank you in advance for your time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(*) - (*) (\(<->\))(#q/)' '$1 $3 $2'
```

Remove `-n` (dry-run) when happy.